# "End" key results in "<select> is undefined" after updating to 24bit color gnu-screen

Tags: terminal-emacs, terminfo

In order to get Doom colours working properly in a `screen` session within Konsole, the KDE terminal, I upgraded to the latest `screen` version from the `screen` repo in order to get the theme colours working properly. Everything appears to work fine except

The `End` key does not work properly and results in a `<select> is undefined` message displaying.

Any experience of this?

I tested it in Vim as well and the `End` key works as expected so it seems the problem lies in Emacs.

After testing in `xterm` and `kitty` the problem doesn't exist in those terminals, so I suspect it is down to some flaw in KDE's `konsole`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your terminal `Emacs` session try this

```lisp
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "<select>") (kbd "<end>"))
```

and see if the problem goes away.  (It should)

This is a temporary band-aid solution.  You need to collect more information to fix this problem cleanly.

In your `*scratch*` buffer, can you do `C-q`, followed by the pressing of `End` key, and post a screenshot of what you see there.  This will help us see the "raw" stuff that terminal is sending to `Emacs`.

I also suggest that you see if there are any changes to `terminfo` files.  Btw, are you working on a remote machine (emacsclient/server), or is it all on the same machine?

---

What does `C-h k End` report.

On my end, on `xterm` it reports the key as `<end>`.

The only trace of `[select]` in `xterm.el` is in

[`(define-key map "\e[4~" [select])`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/term/xterm.el?h=6b560992681a1588ed4ed0c6b103021f8b13e056#n158)

and the only trace of `[end]` in `xterm.el` is [`(define-key map "\eOF" [end])`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/term/xterm.el?h=6b560992681a1588ed4ed0c6b103021f8b13e056#n280), both defined as part of [`xterm-rxvt-function-map`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/term/xterm.el?h=6b560992681a1588ed4ed0c6b103021f8b13e056#n154)

[`xterm-rxvt-function-map` is a parent map of `xterm-function-map`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/term/xterm.el?h=6b560992681a1588ed4ed0c6b103021f8b13e056#n197) and is pushed on to the [`input-decode-map`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/term/xterm.el?h=6b560992681a1588ed4ed0c6b103021f8b13e056#n879)

---

What is the value  of `TERM`?

In `gnome-terminal`, I get

```
~$ env | grep TERM
COLORTERM=truecolor
GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN=/org/gnome/Terminal/screen/7c41a066_78c0_4cf5_bd9b_7b51193e3fed
TERM=xterm-256color
GNOME_TERMINAL_SERVICE=:1.107
```

In `xterm`, I get

```
~$ env | grep  TERM
XTERM_VERSION=XTerm(372)
XTERM_SHELL=/bin/bash
XTERM_LOCALE=en_IN
TERM=xterm
```

The value that is reported is then looked up in `term-file-aliases` to make terminal specific configuration.

I see no entry for `konsole` in `term-file-aliases` (possibly because I am running GNOME Desktop?).

---

`term-file-aliases` is a variable defined in `faces.el`.

Its value is shown below.

Alist of terminal type aliases.  Entries are of the form (`TYPE` . `ALIAS`), where both elements are strings.  This means to treat a terminal of type `TYPE` as if it were of type `ALIAS`.

This variable was introduced, or its default value was changed, in version 25.1 of Emacs.  You can customize this variable.

Value:

```lisp
(("apollo" . #1="vt100")
 ("vt102" . #1#)
 ("vt125" . #1#)
 ("vt201" . #2="vt200")
 ("vt220" . #2#)
 ("vt240" . #2#)
 ("vt300" . #2#)
 ("vt320" . #2#)
 ("vt400" . #2#)
 ("vt420" . #2#)
 ("alacritty" . #3="xterm")
 ("foot" . #3#))
```

A quick look at [konsole.el](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/term/konsole.el?h=6b560992681a1588ed4ed0c6b103021f8b13e056#n8) suggests that it considers `konsole` just the same as `xterm`.

Since you say that you don't have issues with `xterm`, on `konsole`, why don't you start `Emacs` with

```
TERM=xterm emacs -nw
```

etc etc

and see if the problem goes away.

---

A quick look of where `[end]` is defined in `Emacs` source.

```
-*- mode: rg; default-directory: "~/src/emacs/lisp/" -*-
rg started at Tue Oct 18 11:45:27

/usr/bin/rg --color=always --colors=match:fg:red --colors=path:fg:magenta --colors=line:fg:green --colors=column:none -n --column --type-add=gyp\:\*.gyp --type-add=gyp\:\*.gypi -i --heading --no-config --type=elisp -e \\\[end\\\]

File: term/AT386.el
  42  38     (define-key AT386-keypad-map "Y" [end])

File: term/iris-ansi.el
 240  31     (define-key map "\e[146q" [end])
 301  33     ;;(define-key map "\e[146q" [end])

File: term/xterm.el
 280  28     (define-key map "\eOF" [end])

File: term/rxvt.el
  45  29     (define-key map "\e[8~" [end])

File: term/ns-win.el
 161  24 (define-key global-map [end] 'end-of-buffer)

File: term.el
 942  21     (define-key map [end] 'term-send-end)

File: term/wyse50.el
  60  25                ("\e\^^"    [end])

File: emulation/edt-pc.el
  82  41     ("SELECT" . [delete]) ("PREVIOUS" . [end]) ("NEXT" . [next])

File: eshell/em-term.el
 323  35 ;  (define-key eshell-term-raw-map [end] 'eshell-term-send-end)

File: bindings.el
1180  24 (define-key global-map [end]       'move-end-of-line)
1183  24 (define-key esc-map    [end]       'end-of-buffer-other-window)

File: hexl.el
 129  21     (define-key map [end] 'hexl-end-of-line)

File: forms.el
 273   4 ;; [end]     forms-last-record

rg finished (14 matches found) at Tue Oct 18 11:45:27
```

A quick look at where `[select]` is defined `Emacs` source

```
-*- mode: rg; default-directory: "~/src/emacs/lisp/" -*-
rg started at Tue Oct 18 11:47:24

/usr/bin/rg --color=always --colors=match:fg:red --colors=path:fg:magenta --colors=line:fg:green --colors=column:none -n --column --type-add=gyp\:\*.gyp --type-add=gyp\:\*.gypi -i --heading --no-config --type=elisp -e \\\[select\\\]

File: term/xterm.el
 158  29     (define-key map "\e[4~" [select])

File: term/lk201.el
  15  29     (define-key map "\e[4~" [select])

File: term/news.el
  48  38     (define-key news-fkey-prefix "b" [select])

File: emulation/edt-lk201.el
  52  17     ("SELECT" . [select]) ("PREVIOUS" . [prior]) ("NEXT" . [next])

File: textmodes/bibtex.el
3753  28       (define-key menu-map [select]

File: bindings.el
1187  27 ;; (define-key global-map [select] 'function-key-error)

File: obsolete/tpu-edt.el
 321  21     (define-key map [select] #'tpu-unselect)       ; Select
 495  21     (define-key map [select] #'tpu-select)     ; Select

rg finished (8 matches found) at Tue Oct 18 11:47:24
```

---

From

- [22.14 Keymaps for Translating Sequences of Events | Emacs Docs](https://emacsdocs.org/docs/elisp/Translation-Keymaps#variable-local-function-key-map)
- [40.1.3 Terminal-Specific Initialization](https://emacsdocs.org/docs/elisp/Terminal_002dSpecific)

```lisp
(info "(elisp) Translation Keymaps")
```

Translation keymaps take effect only after Emacs has decoded the keyboard input (via the input coding system specified by `keyboard-coding-system`).  *Note Terminal `I`/`O` Encoding::.

-- Variable: `input-decode-map` This variable holds a keymap that describes the character sequences sent by function keys on an ordinary character terminal.

The value of `input-decode-map` is usually set up automatically according to the terminal's Terminfo or Termcap entry, but sometimes those need help from terminal-specific Lisp files.  Emacs comes with terminal-specific files for many common terminals; their main purpose is to make entries in `input-decode-map` beyond those that can be deduced from Termcap and Terminfo.  *Note Terminal-Specific::.

-- Variable: `local-function-key-map` This variable holds a keymap similar to `input-decode-map` except that it describes key sequences which should be translated to alternative interpretations that are usually preferred.  It applies after `input-decode-map` and before `key-translation-map`.

Entries in `local-function-key-map` are ignored if they conflict with bindings made in the minor mode, local, or global keymaps.  I.e., the remapping only applies if the original key sequence would otherwise not have any binding.

`local-function-key-map` inherits from `function-key-map`.  The latter should only be altered if you want the binding to apply in all terminals, so using the former is almost always preferred.

-- Variable: `key-translation-map`

This variable is another keymap used just like `input-decode-map` to translate input events into other events.  It differs from `input-decode-map` in that it goes to work after `local-function-key-map` is finished rather than before; it receives the results of translation by `local-function-key-map`.

Just like `input-decode-map`, but unlike `local-function-key-map`, this keymap is applied regardless of whether the input key-sequence has a normal binding.  Note however that actual key bindings can have an effect on `key-translation-map`, even though they are overridden by it.  Indeed, actual key bindings override `local-function-key-map` and thus may alter the key sequence that `key-translation-map` receives.  Clearly, it is better to avoid this type of situation.